# Can't install FUELCMS not redirecting to page properly

Tags: php, fuelcms

I am installing the fuelcms I followed the instructions in the guide except the file permission because I am using xampp on windows.

I change the configuration properly in the files but when I navigate using this link I redirected to the xampp index page.

```
http://localhost/fuelcms/fuel
```

I don't know how to install it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the same problem and solved by altering the .htaccess located in the root of the fuel folder like it asks for in the installation page. In your case, you'd have to make sure your htaccess is like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fuelcms

<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Allow asset folders through
RewriteRule ^(fuel/modules/(.+)?/assets/(.+)) - [L]

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(fuel/install/.+|fuel/crons/.+|fuel/data_backup/.+|fuel/codeigniter/.+|fuel/modules/.+|fuel/application/.+) - [F,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]

# Prevents access to dot files (.git, .htaccess) - security.
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```